# jQuery - Object [object Object] has no method 'on'

Tags: jquery, overriding

I am constructing part of a HTML page and I am using jQuery 1.8 and the ".on" function. Somehow, the jQuery version of the page after running:

```
$().jquery;
```

is 1.6.3 and the ".on" method is not found.

Is it possible an old version of jQuery to be rendered after I included mine and it to overwrites the new one?If this happens how can I stop it and why the "on" function is not available if there is no such function in the older version?

Something strange is that If I view the page source only link to my version is available. So, if a older version is loaded in one of the page's frames, why they are overwriting my jQuery version?

Comment: why are you using two versions of jquery? and can you give link to your page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The version that has been loaded last (comes last in your code) - that will be used. Or it will give you an error alltogether and you'll have to use [`.noConflict()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) for the second one.

Also *"If I view the page source only link to my version is available"* then you really shouldn't expect the remote version to work. Make sure it is included correctly.

Comment: I suppose there is no way to fix this issue easy and I should find where the other versions is loaded and updated it?

Comment: JS files usually included in headers or footers, so try to look there

Comment: Thanks for the .noConflict() proposal.

Comment: actually using .noConflict() after my jquery 1.8 is loaded solve the problem at all. As I ready, thins functions replace $ with JQuery. So, in my case, the second jquery library is interpreted as other js lib that is using the $ sign. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to say without seeing your page, but try using the Webkit developer tools in Safari or Chrome or else use FireBug in FireFox to find out where the other jquery is loading form.

In Chrome just open the developer tools, go to the Network tab and then refresh your site. Then look through all the loaded assets to determine where and when the other jQuery code is loading.

Answer (score 0):

I have a same problem a few days. To solve the problem simply upgrade to version 1.18.1 Here is [Download v1.8.1](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.1.min.js) link.